# Migrating a Test subdirectory to a Root in multisite

Tags: sql, wordpress, testing, root, migrate

I have cloned my main site using the plugin WP-Clone to a folder and installed wordpress on it (Mysite.com/test) and have spent about a month adding features and installing plugins and adding pages and improvements. Now I want to move the wordpress installation DB and themes and plugins and pages to mysite.com.

Note : I have another site installed , so its not just mysite.com.

I have tried restoring my test backup on the main site. And caused major problems to it. ( subdirectory folder in URL showing , Screwing up my themes , blocking me from logging in to wp-login.php , 404 page not found , and that stuff)

Is there a more easier and less troubling way to migrate or transfer my files over without screwing around the core root installation?

Thanks alot!! appreciate all the help !!!

Comment: Do you have access to the files via FTP? You can download the files this way and then reupload the necessary ones - plugins, themes, uploads, etc. Then Export all the content via the dashboard and Import on the new install.

Comment: Yes I do have access to the files in webroot. How do I go about this?

Comment: This way is to upload the necessary folders from the test site to the new install, activate theme, activate plugins, copy widgets across, and then import the exported content from xml. This link may help you better: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_to_a_New_Server

Comment: Thanks , I Have tried moving wordpress but to no avail. I will try out the export import function. Thanks!